# vb2008 match text between html tags

Tags: vb.net

hello i'm using `Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition`

how is it possible to match text between tags?

for example i have a string : `<data>Text</data>more text...`, how i can get the `Text` which is inside `<data></data>` ( **.Replace** won't help).

thanks

**My solution :**

```
    Public Function parseText(ByVal str As String, ByVal tag As String) As String
        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(str, "<" & tag & "\b[^>]*>(.*?)</" & tag & ">")
        If match.Groups.Count = 2 Then
            Return match.Groups(1).Value
        Else
            Return "0"
        End If
    End Function
```

I use this because in my case the tags will be always without `id, class, width, href, src, style ....` just tag name (`ex:<data><str><text>...`)

Comment: Can you provide more information? It is always going to be between `<data>` tags, or any arbitrary tags?

Comment: What format is the string? That is, HTML, XML, something else (unstructured)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegularExpressions.

```
    Dim s As String = "<data>Hello world</data>"
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(s, "<data\b[^>]*>(.*?)</data>")

    Dim text As String

    If match.Groups.Count = 2 Then
        text = match.Groups(1).Value
    End If
```

Comment: So, what happens if the tags are not `<data>` tags? I suggest reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to see why RegEx is **not** suitable for arbitrary HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML string and then query the resulting object for the values you want.

The source download comes with many example projects.

Comment: thanks, very useful!, but the second answer is easier, so i marked it as answer, thanks again

Comment: @John - easier and not as good. It is specific for `<data>` tags. I also suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to see why `RegEx` is not a good idea for parsing arbitrary HTML.

Comment: i updated first post, so you can see why second answer will help me, i haven't mentioned some information before, it's my fault.., but your answer it's very good i will use it in the future, but now regex is my solution.

Comment: @John - As I said, RegEx is not suitable for _arbitrary_ HTML parsing. If your HTML is _not_ arbitrary, RegEx is fine.

Comment: ok thanks, when you said "arbitrary" i understood any tag like a, b, td, table, div.. and not <div id="DivId">..

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
Dim findtext2 As String = "(?<=<data>)(.*?)(?=</data>)"
Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox1.Text 'Your HTML code
Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
Dim matches2 As String = ""
For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
    matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches2) 'Results
```

Don't forget `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Above code is getting all information between 2 strings, in this case - `<data>` and `</data>`. You can use whatever you want (it doesn't need to be tag, not even html).